# Why is the VMware Player 3.1.3 Enter Unity menu disabled (grayed out)?

Tags: vmware

I'm using the free VMware Player 3.1.1 and the Unity menu is disabled. Any ideas why?

Host is Windows 7 (Pro) 32-bit.
Guest is Windows XP (converted to VMware from Windows XP Mode Virtual PC guest).

**I've tried** removing and reinstalling the VMware tools and restarting the Guest O/S and installed all 52 Windows XP updates.  No love :(

The only thing similar I found suggested the above:
http://communities.VMware.com/message/1064478#1064478

Comment: It's also greyed out when the VMWare Player is in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered by accident that it's enabled only in my primary Monitor (despite the fact that one of my secondary monitor's is identical to my primary).

When I happened to move the Vmware Player Windows to my primary, the Enable Unity option was enabled. (Did a little A/B/A test to verify that).